# How do I find all solutions to $\cos(x)^4-\sin(x)^4 = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

The interval, when graphing this function, is that the equation is true every $x \in \{0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi\dots\}$ but how do I prove that this is the only solution?

My assumption is that the solution $\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2=1$ could help me out, but I haven't really figured it out.

Comment: Can you factor $u^4 - v^4$?

Comment: The key here is to express everything with only one term (cos(x) for example). Then you have an equation in cos(x). If you are lucky you can solve this new equation and then you find the values of x with argcos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$1=\cos^4x-\sin^4x=(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)=\cos2x$$

$$\iff2x=2n\pi$$ where $n$ is any integer

Had the equation been $$\cos^4x-\sin^4x=-1$$ $$\iff2x=(2m+1)\pi$$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 3):

Late to the game, but I thought I'd chime in.

Given that the ranges of $\cos^4 x$ and $\sin^4 x$ are $[0,1]$, the only way the difference can be $1$ is if $\cos^4 x = 1$ and $\sin^4 x = 0$.

This leads to $\cos x = \pm 1$ or $x = n\pi$, where $n$ is any integer.

Comment: It would be nice if you may replace $\{0,1\}$ with $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

With $t=\cos^2(x)$, you have

$$t^2-(1-t)^2=1,$$ which simplifies to

$$t=1.$$

Then

$$\cos(x)=\pm1$$ for all $x=k\pi$.

Comment: probably you've lost square of $1-t$ in the beginning

Comment: @Mihail: ooops, quite right. Fixing.